# Android design suggestion for reusing activity class & listview adapter instance

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-activity, android-listview

In read through some of the design approaches for android and was wondering what would be the best approach to accomplish this ?

1. Activity_Parent is launched & its an instance of ***DataListActivity.java***
2. It contains a list view and an corresponding adapter to render the view
3. An AsyncTask is fired and the adapter instance is passed to the adapter to fetch list data
4. Upon fetching the data, the list is prepared in doInBackground()
5. onPostExecute() the list is set on the adapter and notifyDatasetChanged()
6. Activity_Parent - **Controller**
7. ListView - **View**
8. Adapter - **Model**
9. AsyncTask - Data fetcher
10. When user wants to see a filtered version of this list

    - Then another activity is launched from Activity_Parent and is called Activity_Child
    - Its also instance of the ***DataListActivity.java***
    - Now I want to reuse the model(i.e, adapter & data) for the listview within Activity_Child so that I dont have to re-fetch data over network.

My suggestion

- StartActivityForResult() from parent and launch child
- Pass the adapter instance from the parent and child
- If adapter as reference of context then update it
- Re-use the adapter to render the child activity's list view

I would like to hear suggestions from you guys on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think if I were you I'd try to implement it as best you can (Get it working) and then submit it to the Exchange site that does code reviews (can't remember the name, codereview? Refactoring? Anyway, I know there is one).  Implementing it that first time is a very important step---writing something and then finding problems and rewriting it is MUCH more educational than picking the best suggestion and implementing it.

Comment: @ Singleton pattern suggestion ::: Wouldn't I leak the context if I use Singleton pattern since its going to live longer than the activity itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, first of all I would ask myself a question if I need a second Activity? Why just using filter in adapter is not an option? Secondly if you really need the same data in your second Activity, then consider making it `Parcelable` and then you can pass it inside Intent bundle, so you really don't need pass the whole adapter, because it is not essentially your data, but instead you should only pass items, which your ListView and Adapter display.

**UPD:** If you decided to use filtering and, for example, use ArrayAdapter, then it already implements Filterable interface, so you can just override `getFilter` method to supply your new filter and then invoke `getFilter().filter(..)` with your constraints, which would perform filtering. And if you don't use ArrayAdapter, you can just make your Adapter implement `Filterable` interface and do the same thing. Also if you need some code examples you can refer to the source code of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: "Why just using filter in adapter is not an option?" -  Any pointers on this ?

Comment: For example if you use ArrayAdapter, then it already implements `Filterable` interface, so you can just override `getFilter` method to supply your new filter and then invoke `getFilter().filter(..)` with your constraints, which would perform filtering. And if you don't use ArrayAdapter, you can just make your Adapter implement `Filterable` interface and do the same thing. Also if you need some code examples you can refer to the source code of ArrayAdapter (which is more preferable) or I can post some code too.

Comment: The Filterable interface seems to solve my question. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome :) So you can mark this as an answer if it helped :)

Comment: Can you move the "Filterable" comment to answer so that I can mark and it wud be useful for others